# AdjustPan not working on first touch when editText has no focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, adjustpan

Long search on stack and other forums gave no results. So the problem: I have recyclerView with items that contains EditText. Activity is NOT in full-screen mode and windowSoftInputMode is 'adjustPan'. When I click on editText for the first time (editText has no focus) - keyboard is overlap editText, however if I close keyboard and touch same editText second time (editText has focus) - adjustPan works as expected and push content up to show editText. This is not flaky bug. Maybe someone already encountered this problem (bug?). Thanks.

Comment: Usually this problem is resolved with a `ScrollView or a NestedScrollView`. Can assist you better if you have your code in your post.

Comment: Wow I just encountered this, Did you solve it?